# Is there any principal difference between "A-Z" and upper?

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

I just want to make sure I understood this correctly.

```
(rx (one-or-more (any upper lower)))
```

is equal to

```
(rx (one-or-more (any "A-Z" "a-z")))
```

Correct?

Comment: `[A-Z]` matches only an *ASCII* uppercase letter, that is, a letter from `A` through `Z`. There are other, non-ASCII uppercase letters (e.g., in languages other than English).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The macro `rx` returns regexp strings that can be passed to other Emacs functions.

```
ELISP> (rx (one-or-more (any upper lower)))
"[[:lower:][:upper:]]+"
ELISP> (rx (one-or-more (any "A-Z" "a-z")))
"[A-Za-z]+"
```

That doesn't answer your question directly; it pushes the question to "are these two regexes identical?" So, let's look for an uppercase or lowercase letter that is not between `A` and `Z`, or `a` and `z`. Let's try `á`.

```
ELISP> (string-match-p (rx (one-or-more (any upper lower))) "á")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (string-match-p (rx (one-or-more (any "A-Z" "a-z"))) "á")
nil
```

So the regexes are not identical. Presumably you want to use `(rx (one-or-more (any upper lower)))` most of the time; it not only includes characters most people think of as letters, but I'd argue is also more readable.